# Can't get babel and webpack to transpile my components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Maybe a newbie issue.  I've installed react and webpack, set up configurations as per documentation and trying to get a simple react component to transpile from a .jsx file to a .js file. The file is created with a stack of boilerplate code but no component is exported.

Here's how the webpack.config.js looks:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

const config = {
    entry: {
    firstcomponent: './wwwroot/jsx/myfirstcomponent.jsx',
},
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        clean: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                use: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
};

module.exports = config;
```

And the babel.config.js

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "throwIfNamespace": false, // defaults to true
        "runtime": "automatic" // defaults to classic
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

and the .babelrc file

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

When I run the build I get a file of 6.86k created which starts with this

```
/*! For license information please see firstcomponent.bundle.js.LICENSE.txt */
(()=>{"use strict";var e={251:(e,t,r)=>{var n=r(294);Symbol.for("react.element"),Symbol.for("react.fragment"),Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty,n.__SECRET_INTERNALS_DO_NOT_USE_OR_YOU_WILL_BE_FIRED.ReactCurrentOwner},408:(e,t)=>
```

The actual test component looks like this

```
export default function HelloWorld()
{
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
            <p>Welcome to my React app.</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Build command looks like this

```
 "build:webpack": "webpack --mode production",
"build": "npm run build:webpack",
"start": "npx webpack --mode development --watch"
```

I've also tried running the build in development mode.  That seems to actually export the component but i have not been able to successfully call it.  I'm an old dev who is trying to learn this stuff but stuck on the 1st hurdle!! Any help gratefully received.

Comment: Slightly off topic, but I would recommend against manually configuring webpack if you're trying to learn React. Webpack has its own learning curve. If you want to start a simple React SPA, then try out [Create React App](https://create-react-app.dev/) or [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project). Create React App also has an eject function that will give you a working webpack config.